# Cant recieve packets sent to my own IP (Python UDP sockets) **FIXED**

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, networking

So I have a typical UDP server and client.
The server is bound to IP '0.0.0.0' port 20000.
From what I know it will bind to any IPv4 address that is from my host computer
including my internal IP of 192.168.1.2 for example. However I receive messages when they are sent to localhost (127.0.0.1), but not when my client sends to my own computers internal IP address like the code below. My internal IP was obtained from cmd ipconfig. **BOTH APPLICATIONS RUN ON THE SAME COMPUTER**

server code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0',20000))
print("listening at 0.0.0.0 at port 20000")
data,address= s.recvfrom(65535)
print "MESSAGE FROM",address,":",data
s.close()
```

client code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1',50000))
s.sendto("MESSAGE1!",('192.168.1.2',20000))   
print 'message sent!'
s.close()
```

> **SOLUTION: I found out I can't send a packet to an "external" ip 192.168.1.2 from a client socket, when it is bound to a localhost ip e.g 127.0.0.1. By changing the client socket to 192.168.1.2, I am able to send it to its own external ip 192.168.1.2**

Comment: it may help to try and disable your firewall (temporarily) on the computer to see if your connection is being blocked

Comment: im sending 2 packets to and from the same machine

Answer (score 0):

'192.168.1.2' is a private IP address.  Your client won't be able to see that.  You'll need to pay for an IP address, make it available, configure your router properly, and configure your firewall properly.

Comment: Im running the code from the same machine. Anyway I have solved my own problem, thank you very much for taking the time to reply though. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

There is still an error in your code even though you got it to work.

A client does not use bind().

bind() is a server side function.

Your client code should be this:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto("MESSAGE1!",('192.168.1.2',20000))   
print 'message sent!'
s.close()
```